# Mod_Color.cs(55,55): Error CS0241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted (CS0241) (Assembly-CSharp)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compilation

I get this error while trying to compile something in C# (In monodevelop unity)
Please tell me how can i fix it

```
Mod_Color.cs(55,55): Error CS0241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted (CS0241) (Assembly-CSharp)
```

Code:

```
namespace TestHack.RENDER
{
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class Mod_Color
    {
        private Color color;

        public Mod_Color(float r, float g, float b, float a = 255f)
        {
            this.color = new Color(r / 255f, g / 255f, b / 255f, a / 255f);
        }

        public Color Get()
        {
            return this.color;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Monodevelop are you using, and which version of Unity?

Comment: Latest of both. Do you have skype?

Comment: No, that's not the way it works - Stack Overflow isn't a gateway to a personal debugging service. Edit your question to specify the precise version numbers, and anything else relevant.

Comment: Pretty sure if Jon gave out his personal contact information he'd never get any sleep, but if you want his email just pick up one of his books :) Not that he should answer anything about topics outside the book though.

Answer (score 0):

Use two overloads:

```
public class Mod_Color
{
    private Color color;

    public Mod_Color(float r, float g, float b)
    {
        this.color = Mod_Color(r, g, b, 255f);
    }

    public Mod_Color(float r, float g, float b, float a)
    {
        this.color = new Color(r / 255f, g / 255f, b / 255f, a / 255f);
    }

    public Color Get()
    {
        return this.color;
    }
}
```

It seems you are using a .NET framework or Mono framework that doesn't support default parameter specifiers. Using an overload works the same way without having to modify existing code.

Comment: c:\Users\NewFix\Documents\New Unity Project\Assets\RENDER\Mod_Color.cs(9,9): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Color' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) (TestHack)

Comment: Where is the `Color` namespace that you are using? Do you have `using UnityEngine;` at the top of your class file?